# Caching likes a follow state iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, swift

I'm building a small social network. I quite far already. But now I need to implement a caching system.
In my app I can like things and follow other peoples. So what I want:

- When I like a recipe it automatically counts up the number of likes. In the whole app without to reload a page
- When I follow someone the it aitmomatically counts up the number of followers. In the whole app aswell without reloading anything.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?
I'm working with swift.

Thank you :D

Comment: The 2 hardest problems in programming - cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-1 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an in-memory cache try the following library:
http://realm.io

If you need some kind of persistent database here are some options:

- [YapDatabase](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase) (key-value SQLite wrapper)
- [Realm.io](http://realm.io) (it fits for such purposes too)
- [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (seems that it is too complicated solution for your issue)

Answer (score -1):

This might help to you in caching, which code has written in swift. Code is [here](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift)!